# Display a certain amount of data for each range of data value in HiveQL

Tags: hive, count, range

I'm a newbie here and newbie to HiveQL. I'd like to ask how to display a certain amount of data for each range of data value in HiveQL? For example I have this set of data:

```
Name    Age
A       34
B       38
C       39
D       35
E       26
F       34
G       34
H       26
I       27
J       27
K       30
L       31
M       42
N       39
O       37
P       22
Q       19
R       20
S       40
```

And I'd like to display ONLY three people in each age group 16-25, 26-35, 36-45 (display theirs name+age). And also if you don't mind, would you please explain in briefly about partition, since I don't have a good grasp in this part.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this.

```
select name,age from 
(select name,age,row_number() over (partition by age_group order by name desc)  as rn
from (select name,age ,case when age between 16 and 25 then 20 when age between 26 and 35 then 30 when age between 36 and 45 then 40 else 0 end as "age_group" from table) t1 where age_group != 0) t2
where rn <=3
group by name,age
```

I have divided ages in age groups ie 16 - 25 becomes 20s, 26-35 becomes 30s and so on.
The used partition by age_group and given each group by different rownumbers.
In this case if 20s age group has 4 records then using partition by clause it will given 1,2,3,4 rowNumbers and for 30s if it has 3 records it will be given 1,2,3 rownumbers.
And at last filtering rows having more than 3 rows for each group.

Comment: It works! Thanks Pankaj! Finally I got what partition is :)